# $expiration_duration = apply_filters( 'password_reset_expiration', DAY_IN_SECONDS );

Tags: password

Can you better explain the operation of this line of code and how can I set the password recovery link to 60 minutes?

```
$expiration_duration = apply_filters( 'password_reset_expiration', DAY_IN_SECONDS );
```

Thanks a lot to those who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

in general we use WordPress filters to make changes for data. so in this code the filter `password_reset_expiration` allows us to make changes in it's parameter `DAY_IN_SECONDS` which equals `86400 seconds`.

so we can change this value by adding a function that returns a new value to this filter:

```
add_filter( 'password_reset_expiration', function( $expiration ) {
    return MONTH_IN_SECONDS;
});
```

this function changes the expiration time to be last for one month

we can also change to to any count of seconds

```
add_filter( 'password_reset_expiration', function( $expiration ) {
    return 60; // One minute
});
```

`the upper codes are working in theme functions.php or your plugin files. just be sure to pass an integer for the seconds number`